# Reset all checkboxes on page without looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it was possible to reset all the checkboxes (mark them unchecked) on the page without looping using jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a single selector to find all the checked checkboxes, and remove the 'checked' attribute from them. jQuery will do this internally by looping, but you will not have to write a loop yourself:

```
 $(':checkbox:checked').removeAttr('checked');
```

See the [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) and [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selectors.