# Check/uncheck all checkboxes on without looping and without a framework

Tags: javascript, checkbox, no-framework

Is it possible to check or uncheck a set of checkboxes on a page a) without looping, and b) without using a Javascript framework such a jQuery?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760982/reset-all-checkboxes-on-page-without-looping) is related but is about (un)checking all the checkboxes on a page with jQuery.

I expect the answer to my question will probably be "no", but if there's some weird, hacky way of doing it (not weird and not hacky is good too!) then I would like to know.  Call it curiosity if you will.

Edit: I suppose what I'm really asking is for a way to do it in O(1) (constant time) rather than O(n) (linear time with respect to the number of checkboxes)

Comment: There isn't a way to do this without looping. Even by using a class with vanilla JS, you'll still need to write a handler to grab every element with that class. There isn't a problem with using a loop anyway :-) (or is there, in this particular situation?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may modify/override the full HTML code:

```
<div id="checkBoxes">
<input name="foo" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="bar" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="baz" type="checkbox" value="1" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkAll(){
    document.getElementById("checkBoxes").innerHTML = 
         '<input name="foo" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />'
        +'<input name="bar" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />'
        +'<input name="baz" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />';
}
function uncheckAll(){
    document.getElementById("checkBoxes").innerHTML = 
         '<input name="foo" type="checkbox" value="1" />'
        +'<input name="bar" type="checkbox" value="1" />'
        +'<input name="baz" type="checkbox" value="1" />';
}
</script>
```

no Loop, no Framework, just a little bit unesthetic..

Comment: +1 and accepted answer.  You should be both proud and ashamed of yourself for thinking of this!! :D

Answer (score 2):

If the buttons are in a form, you can use a reset button if the default state is unchecked and you don't mind resetting all the other controls in the form. Otherwise, you have to use a loop regardless of whether you use POJS or a "framework".

Look ma, no script!

```
<form action="#">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb3">
    <br>
    <input type="reset" value="Uncheck all">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: A good way of unchecking all, but doesn't allow for checking them all.  Thanks for the response, though.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with map(), which may or may not be a loop, depending on how strict of a definition you use for "loop" :)  But in all practical terms, it's just another way of casting a loop.  I'd say the answer to your question is "no."

---

**EDIT:**

```
var checkboxes = getElement...
checkboxes.map(function(c) {
    c.checked = true;
});
```

Comment: +1 and thanks.  Could you give a quick example (or link) showing how to do it with map(), please? :)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can go about checking or unchecking a set of checkboxes on a page is to reference each one individually.

This meets both criteria "a" (no looping) and criteria b (no framework)

Comment: +1 - Clever and does fit within my rules.  I don't think I asked the question very well...